# Programatic Registry editing blocked

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

I am seeing a situation where a PowerShell script can't write to the Software key of the Local Machine hive, but the user can manually do it in Regedit. Is there a Group Policy that would limit programatic access but not manual access?

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: At this point we have tried running as a regular user, as a local administrator, and as an administrator with elevated privileges. All fail. We did get one run, on a freshly built VM, where an early write to registry worked, and a later one didn't, which sounds to me like Group Policy getting applied in the background as the script is running. The script is installing Autodesk software, which can take literally hours, so plenty of time for GP to be applied while the script is running.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. provide basic part of Powershell code as well as full error message.

Comment: There isn't an example, that's the problem. The code I am using WORKS, on 99% of machines in the office. But a few have something going on with GPO that blocks writing to the registry. I was hoping someone recognizes a policy that would create this behavior. Looks like we'll have to do it the hard way.